# How to draw images on Terrain in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on game in unity in which i need some images to be placed on terrain as in the attached image yellow arrows and "P in blue circle" are rendered on surface in unity.

Any idea or method will be appreciated.

[image: Arrows in Unity]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built-in support for decals in Unity. You could just create separate gameObjects with transparent texture and place them above the terrain here, or use one of several packages for decals in Unity Asset Store, like [this one](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/141792-Decal-System). (I have only briefly tried it and can't say anything about it's quality).

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old topic - but for those who are still not satisfied:

I would recommend using [Easy Decal](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/22867).

It's a very powerful decal projector. It's easy to use and you can stick decals also on uneven surfaces like bumpy terrains.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting a plane with the texture aligned with the surface normal slightly above the surface. Or you could try an extension that does decals for you. This is what i found:

[Decal System for Unity3D](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/3779)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to download the Decal System package but it gives error i.e Couldn't resolve host name url: https://kharma.unity3d.com/

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned Easy decal is a good choice. It's easy to use, has extensive fuctionalities and you'll get a lot for your money. But if you need skinned decals there's no way around Decal System Pro by Edelweiss interactive. It's more expensive, but beside the skinned mesh support it also supports texture atlases which saves you draw calls.